# Select all the text or characters between 2 text patterns that are repeating

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Following is the sample .log file (there can be more lines in this)

```
2022 User abc (iii)
2023 defaa <party> ttt
2222221 User def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun> ttt
2222 User dddd (aaa)
3333 defaa <hahaha> jmd
```

I want to select lines between `User` & `ttt`

Please note that these are like 5-7 lines of the log, there can be more lines in this log consisting of `User` & `ttt`

So i want to know a way to get all the lines between `User` & `ttt` even if they are repeated across the file

The text `User` & `ttt` are not always on consecutive lines

Expected Output:

```
abc (iii)
2023 defaa <party> 
def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun>
```

---

In case of nesting, as in the following:

```
2022 User abc (iii)
2222221 User def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun> ttt
2023 defaa <party> ttt
```

Expected Output:

```
def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun>
```

User & ttt will never be on the same line

Comment: Including or excluding matches? **Show us expected output**

Comment: `User` is on the first line, `ttt` is on the second line: there's no lines in between! That repeats for the third anf fourth line. Hence, there's nothing to select? I'm a bit confused!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion
What i meant is whatever there is between User and ttt

Comment: are these always on consecutive lines?

Comment: Expected Output :
 abc (iii)
2023 defaa <party>
 def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun>

Comment: Not always on consecutive lines

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include that expected output! (basically, add all info you're giving in the comments to your question. Comments are transient. Questions are forever.)

Comment: Edited question :)

Comment: So what do you want to happen when there's nesting, like [this](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/8bf018574833aea25d48bf4b1a0bcf33) example?

Comment: In the nesting scenario I want it to just give the def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun>

Comment: Can `User` and `ttt` also be on the same line?

Comment: No it will not be on the same line

Comment: If "The text User & ttt are not always on consecutive lines" then don't always show them on consecutive lines in your example. Create and show an example that covers all of your requirements to demonstrate those requirements to make them easy for us to see/understand and so we have something to copy/paste to test with. And don't provide a link to an example, include it in your question. Also, include in your example cases where `User` and/or `ttt` appear as substrings, e.g. `BadUserInfo` and `footttbar` so we can see how you want partial matches handled.

Comment: It seems as if what you have are actual _data records_ with some definite _structure_ to them. If you could show the data schema or format (with real readable examples), then it would be easier to help you not only to extract the wanted information but to work with this data in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`, you can select an address range fron `User`to `ttt` and collect in in the hold space:

```
sed '/User/,/ttt/!d;H;/User/h;/ttt/!d;x;s/.*User //;s/ttt.*//' yourfile
```

Detailled explanation:

- `/User/,/ttt/` selects lines in the range from `User` to the next `ttt` (like requested by the nested case); this selection is inverted by `!` and `d`eleted. Thus, this step removes all lines outside this range. Unfortunally, the last piece from the last `User` to the end of the file is *not* removed, so we need a way to get rid of this:
- `H` appends all lines to the hold space, while `/User/h` *copies* lines with `User` to the hold space, so the hold space contains all lines from `User` to the current line. This way a new `User` line overwrites everything before, as expected for the nested case.
- `/ttt/!d` stops execution for all lines without `ttt`, so we don't generate any output until we have collected everything from `User' to` ttt` in the hold space.
- But once we have everything together, we can `x`change the buffers to have those lines from the hold space in our pattern space,
- then remove everything up to `User` with `s/.*User //`
- and remove everything starting from `ttt` with `s/ttt.*//`

Comment: That demonstrates one of the main problems with using a range - if you want to do any more than just print the range inclusive (e.g. exclude start and/or end lines or parts thereof as in this case) then you need to test the same condition(s) multiple times. If the user decided to use `foo` instead of `ttt`, for example (or if they wanted to tighten the match with word boundaries or something), they'd have to change that code, and make sure the new string is identical in all instances, in 3 separate places and ditto for `User`.

Comment: Of course you can use variables for the search pattern, if that is a problem for you. Alternatively, you can make use of the empty expression `//` to repeat the last expression to avoid repetitions: `sed 'H;/.*User/{s///;h;};//,/ttt.*/!d;//!d;x;s///'`. But I prefer not to write such code in answers, because it is harder to read. If I want to write uncomprehensive code, I could use `awk` as well. (-;

Comment: Thanks a lot @Philippos. This worked. I am just going through the detailed explanation.  If anything I will come back to the thread :)

Answer (score 3):

This, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `\s` shorthand for `[:space:]`, might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s*ttt' 'RT && sub(/.*User\s*/,"")' file
abc (iii)
2023 defaa <party>
def (bbb)
20222 defaa <accoun>
```

If you don't want to allow partial matches on `User` and `ttt` then add word boundaries around them:

```
awk -v RS='\\s*\\<ttt\\>' 'RT && sub(/.*\<User\>\s*/,"")' file
```